# SharePoint 2010 Some Lists Don't Show up in Add Alerts Page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, alert

I have been attempting to add an alert to a list in one of my SharePoint 2010 Web Applications and the list does not show up in the list of available items in the Add Alert page.  There are several of them in this Web Application that don't show up while several others do. Does a list need to be configured to allow alerts? Do certain kinds of lists not allow alerts?

Thanks Doug

Answer (score 0):

I turns out that the list in question was set so that only the user that created the list item can read and edit the list item. Apparently SharePoint does not allow you to setup alerts on this type of list, even if you are a farm admin.

It would be nice to have some way around this little limitation. I have a group of administrators that manage a list of maintenance requests. They want the people who create them to be able to edit only their own but the admins should be able to create alerts to know when a new item has been added.